# How did Pryde get to Exegol to participate in the Battle of Exegol?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Did I miss something? Pryde was somewhere else when the Final Order was declared. Did the old First Order ships and crew participated in the Battle of Exegol?

**How did Pryde get to Exegol?**

Comment: Cheers for acceptance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Palpatine sent him the coordinates (and transit details) to get to Exegol.

> The creature in the hologram spoke. “The Princess of Alderaan has disrupted my plan,” said Emperor Palpatine. “But her foolish act will be in vain. Come to me on Exegol, General Pryde.”
>
> “As I served you in the Old Wars, I serve you now.”
>
> The image sputtered. The transmission was weak and fragile, having made a near impossible journey through the Unknown Regions and anomalous space. But it was enough. “Send the ship to a world they know,” Palpatine said, and Pryde’s heart skipped. This was the moment he’d been waiting for. “Let it burn. The Final Order begins. She will come. Her friends will follow.”
>
> As his master grinned—a slow, centipede crawl across his mouth—Allegiant General Pryde shivered in near-ecstasy. “Yes, my lord.”
>
> **A flurry of complex coordinate data followed. The way to Exegol.** The Emperor was trusting him with his most precious knowledge. “Behold, the fruit of your labor,” his master said, as the data streaming toward him revealed another frequency channel.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 15):

Pryde has a private transmission with Palpatine — I think shortly after Rey escapes from Ren’s destroyer — where Palpatine orders Pryde to come to him on Exegol while Ren pursues Rey.

Pryde ends the conversation by assuring the Emperor he will serve him as he did during the earlier war.

Presumably any lightspeed-capable fighter or transport can get you to Exegol once the route is known, since we later see many vessels make the trip without the aid of a wayfinder.